# MySQL LOAD DATA ignore quotes

Tags: mysql

I have not found the right combination of control characters when importing a CSV file.  Actually the file is delimited by caret (^).  Occasionally a field will have embedded quotes which I want to import as literals.  A couple examples of import values are ^""001454483^ and ^""Sambo""^.  If "Fields terminated by" = ^, and enclosed by and escaped by = double quote, then an error is generated.  Adding "enclosed by" set to ^, then it is an endless loop.  Also changing "escaped by" to ~ also creates an endless loop.  I don't have a need to escape the ^.  What settings should I use?

Need to import exactly what is between ^^.

Comment: Please post a sample of a few complete lines that you're trying to import.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
load data ... fields terminated by '^' enclosed by '' ...
```

Comment: Yes, I found this to work.  Null dates in the csv are represented by NULL, however, when imported they get a value of 0000-00-00.  If enclosed by is double quote, then those null dates import as NULL, as desired.  Is there a different way to represent null in the csv?

Comment: @BillParker Simply save NULL to CSV via SELECT INTO OUTFILE and look into.

Comment: In my testing, csv value of \N requires that 'escaped by' = blank.  I would prefer that  'escaped by' != blank and 'enclosed by' = blank, but I can't make that work with \N.  NULL works with 'enclosed by' = ~ and 'escaped by' = | (pipe).  \N works if both are blank.